# Load values from database in modal window on button click always show same data

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have following in my `blade` template

```
@foreach($downloadables as $download)
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#about">Download</a>


     <span id="start" class="target"></span>
     <span id="about" class="target"></span>
     <div class="modal">
        <div class="content vertical-align-middle">
           <h2>Click on the file to download it</h2>
           <article>
               {{$download->doc}}
           </article>
           <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
        </div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Here in the foreach are displayed all downloads and their ID's. Problems:

1. If I have 10 buttons Download, no matter which I click it's always
   show same `doc` in modal window
2. `$download->doc` can have one or more id's like `1,2,3` but on the modal is showing the last one only.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: this is modal window without using JS if is matter.

Update: One button 'Download' can be associated to few files. In database they are saved with comma in the column, like: 1,2,3..

What I receive on the button download now is

```
<a href="files/download/1,2">Download</a>
```

It should be 2 download buttons for each id

```
<a href="files/download/1">Download</a>
<a href="files/download/2">Download</a>
```

Comment: How could you access the `$download` variable outside the `foreach` loop

Comment: Sorry about that. It is inside the loop. My mistake while added it to the question. Will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue in populating the content within the modal, hence changing the placement of the loop would resolve the issue.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#about">Download</a>
<span id="start" class="target"></span>
<span id="about" class="target"></span>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="content vertical-align-middle">
        <h2>Click on the file to download it</h2>
        @foreach($downloadables as $download)
        <article>
            {{--*/ $ids = explode(",", $download->doc); /*--}}
            @foreach ($ids as $id)
            <a href="{{ url("files/download/").$id }}">Download</a>
            @endforeach
        </article>
        @endforeach
        <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This fixed the issue for the modal opening. But it is still showing all id's on button click. I will show example data in the question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: @Ivan How do you get the comma separated id's ? Can you update `dd($downloadables)` ?

Comment: Yes, `dd($download->doc)` return this `string(3) "1,2"`

Comment: Is this `{{--*/ $ids = explode(",", $download->doc); /*--}}` commented?

Comment: No that is a variable declaration in blade syntax

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that this is a way to declare variable in blade. Works perfectly. Thank you very much!